# Construct xml document using custom node class

Tags: python, xml, data-structures, nodes

I've wrote a class to create a node-like object to create a node tree. I have a problem about converting the whole tree into a string with xml markup.

This is shortly how the class looks like:

```py
class Node ():
   parent: Node  # upper node
   children: list[Node]  # list of child node

   def get_tab_count(self) -> int  # used for tabulation
```

I wrote this function that build the string of the xml document:

```py
def to_xml (node, indent = '\t') -> str:
    xml = ''

    stack = [node]
    while (len(stack) > 0):
        node = stack.pop()

        tabs = (indent * len(node.get_tab_count()))
        xml += f'{tabs}<node {"/" if len(node.__children) <= 0 else ""}>\n'

        stack.extend(node.__children)
    return xml
```

And this is the output from an example tree:

```xml
<node >
        <node />
        <node />
        <node />
        <node />
        <node >
                <node />
                <node />
                <node />
        <node />
        <node />
        <node />
```

The problem is that **I can't figure out how to close elements with children nodes**, I searched solutions online. They all use recursions but instead in my function I want to use a stack and an iteration.

What this function is doing is making a list with one element, remove the last element and make a piece of string of the xml, then add all children (if any) to the list and repeat, it will repeat and cycle trough the whole tree.

I feel like I'm just missing something, I can't figure out how to make it work or where to look for a solution.

Comment: Why do you need a custom class? Why not use the built-in ElementTree module to create and manipulate XML?

Comment: You could create fake nodes which are pushed on the stack for elements with children (before the children itself). When the fake node is popped from the stack later, a closing tag is created.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher , can you explain more or show an example? I quite didn't get what a fake node should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a fake node (I call it `CloseNode`) and add it to the stack roughly like so:

```
class CloseNode:

   def get_tab_count(self):
       ...


def to_xml (node, indent = '\t') -> str:
    xml = ''

    stack = [node]
    while (len(stack) > 0):
        node = stack.pop()

        tabs = (indent * len(node.get_tab_count()))
        if isinstance(node, CloseNode):
            xml += f'{tabs}</node>\n'
        else:
            xml += f'{tabs}<node {"/" if len(node.__children) <= 0 else ""}>\n'
            
            if len(node.__children) > 0:
                stack.append(CloseNode())
                stack.extend(node.__children)

    return xml
```

Comment: Ok, that's an interesting way to solve the problem although it defines a class that is only used on that specific method. I'll see what I'll come up with. 